# Load a function after the layout is being added and shown completely

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to show a loading page in windows phone 8.1

I want to call function `this.GetAllRings` after i can see the layout. I have tried added in loaded but it still don't work. Unless the entire query is complete, i see black screen. How can i fix this

Following is my code

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.app = App.Current as App;
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        this.GetAllRings();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to run `this.GetAllRings` in a separate thread.

Comment: @Meneses being a starter, i am not sure how threads work , but what is problem with above?

Comment: it may be blocking the UI thread. Try the folowing instead: `await Task.Run(() => this.GetAllRings());`

Comment: that did it. Thanks mate, u can make it nswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainPage_Loaded method your request is probably blocking the UI thread.
You should try the following:

`await Task.Run(() => this.GetAllRings());`

This should do it.